# Find out database attribute where searchstring was found (with Entity Framework)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I have my searchString and want to search in the db table by a few properties (Name, PhoneNumber, EmailAddress etc.). But I need to know the property where the searchString was found. Is there any elegant solution?
Now I have many similar code blocks (for Name one, for PhoneNumber one, ...) like this:

```
        var searchString = "text to search...";
        var searchResultItems = new List<SearchResultItem>();            
        // Search in client names
        var clients = db.Clients.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString)); // db context
        foreach (var client in clients)
        {
            var searchResultItem = new SearchResultItem()
            {
                ResultLabel = client.Name,
                SearchResultType = SearchResultType.ClientName,
            };
            searchResultItems.Add(searchResultItem);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write it in a more compact way, which in the same time will be better solution from performance perspective (as you will be selecting just single field from the whole table):

```
var nameQuery = db.Clients
    .Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString))
    .Select(x => new SearchResultItem {
        ResultLabel = client.Name,
        SearchResultType = SearchResultType.ClientName,
    });
```

In similar way you create phoneNumberQuery, emailAddressQuery etc.

Then you can `.Concat()` all such pieces into single query like this:

```
var = searchResultItems = nameQuery
    .Concat(phoneNumberQuery)
    .Concat(emailAddressQuery)
    .Concat(...)
    .ToArray();
```

Also you can go expression-way and write method like

```
IQueryable<SearchResultItem> GetSearchQuery<T>(IQueryable<T> set, Expression<Func<T, string>> fieldSelector, string searchString, SearchResultType resultType) {
    // homework here
}
```

which will generate select queries based on specific fields, but in your specific case I don't think that worth it.

Comment: I am not sure it is exactlky what I am looking for (I still have to call the script many times) but it seems better than my solution.